# Is "too localized" a reason to close a question or not?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, close-reasons

I wanted to close [Where to find a training partner for home based practicing?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/6723/where-to-find-a-training-partner-for-home-based-practicing) based of it being too localized to be of any use to wide audience. [JohnP](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/users/548/johnp) kindly pointed out in a comment that

> Too localized hasn't been a close reason for some time.

However, the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) topic page gives:

> Recommendations for schools or teachers in area X (too localized)

**Should `too localized` be a reason to close questions?**

Note that I have no strong preferences either way as most too localized questions generally show no prior research whatsoever so bad questions will get closed in any case. That said, we should be consistent.

Answer (score 4):

*Too localized* is definitely a valid close reason, but you will have to do it manually (Off topic -> Other, enter reason).

IIRC there was a network-wide move away from having it as a pre-canned reason due to misuse - people were using it as a quick convenient catch-all reason to close questions.

Comment: In that case, it might be worthwhile to edit the meta to reflect that change. For those interested: [meta discussion on new close reasons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons)